# Javascript works but JQuery does not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is like this:

```
<script> 
    var name = document.getElementById("nusname").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("uName").innerHTML = "Welcome, " + name;
    $('#uName').text("AsgufHFBS");
</script>
```

The 3rd line

```
document.getElementById("uName").innerHTML = "Welcome, " + name;
```

works but the 4th line

```
$('#uName').text("AsgufHFBS");
```

does not.

I have tried replacing this with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#uName').text("AsgufHFBS");
});
```

but it still does not work.

So my question is this: Why does the javascript work but the not the JQuery version?

Comment: have you loaded the jQuery library? correctly? i.e. show the HTML for the `<script>` element that loads jQueery (it's in the `<head>` right?)

Comment: is there an element with id `uName`... is there an error in the console

Comment: seems like u don't have jQuery lib

Comment: just a thought, Is this a textbox or label?.For textbox it should be val not the text.

Comment: @Hsakarp But `innerHTML` wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: @A.Wolff Textarea allows the innerHTML, just tested out in answer box

Comment: Dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code

Comment: @A.Wolff I think val() will work with input elements and text() will work with the labels,spans,divs.

Comment: @Hsakarp Ya but in these cases, innerHTML would fail too

Comment: @A.Wolff But the way javascript and jquery works different, I hope.The innerHTML is something which will be available for all HTML elements and innerHTML directly writes into the element itself.

Comment: @Hsakarp `input` is void element, it cannot contains any content so innerHTML has no effect  https://jsfiddle.net/6h6982w6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this in the `<head>` of your document:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or simply update your code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
    var name = document.getElementById("nusname").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("uName").innerHTML = "Welcome, " + name;
    $('#uName').text("AsgufHFBS");
</script>
```

Comment: @JamesTan you should wrap the code inside doc ready block or move this script block at the end of body.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have already embedded the jQuery library correctly and it's still not working, try this:

```
jQuery('#uName').text("AsgufHFBS");
```

If that works it means the $ shorthand is likely reserved by another script on your page.  You can either correct that issue, or just preface jQuery commands with "jQuery" rather than "$" on that page.

Answer (score 0):

I have coded your code into jsFiddle and it works fine, however did you include jQuery in your file? If you press f12 in your browser do you get any console logs? If so please provide them.

But here is the jsFiddle version which does include jQuery

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bn788ff4/

Html

```
<div id="nusname">hello</div>
<div id="uName">username</div>
```

Javascript / jQuery

```
var name = document.getElementById("nusname").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("uName").innerHTML = "Welcome, " + name;
$('#uName').text("AsgufHFBS");
```

To include jQuery you can use the hosted version by google

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Link https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing Jquery library files.
Please attach the foolowing to the `<head>` section of your page.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and replace the 4th line of your code with:

```
$('#uName').html("AsgufHFBS");
```